# Polymorphism and Explicit casting of object

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

```
    //code-1
                Emp1 emp11 =  new Emp2(); 
                ((Emp2) emp11).displayEmp2();   

    //code-2
                Emp1 emp11 =  new Emp2(); 
                emp11 = (Emp2) emp11;        //line-1
                (emp11).displayEmp2();       //line-2

class Emp1  {   
    public void displayEmp1(){                
        System.out.println("displayEmp1");      
    }
}

class Emp2 extends Emp1 {
    public void displayEmp2(){
        System.out.println("displayEmp2");          
    }
}
```

Why code-1 is different from code-2.
Code-1 is executing successfully but code-2 is giving compilation error at line-2.
Though, doing the same thing in both piece of code.
I understand that it wont be able to find the method in superclass during compilation time.But my doubt is if already explicitly converting it at line-1 then why it is throwing compilation error. If does it so, then it should also throw error for code-1 also.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: `Emp1 emp11` means `emp11` is a reference to `Emp1`. No amount of casting will change that.

Comment: They are not doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting `emp11` to `Emp2` has no meaning if later you assign it back to `emp11`, whose type is `Emp1`. A variable whose type is `Emp1` allows you only to call methods of class `Emp1`.

In order for the second snippet the behave as the first, you should assign the result of the casting to a variable of type `Emp2` :

```
Emp1 emp11 =  new Emp2(); 
Emp2 emp2 = (Emp2) emp11;
emp2.displayEmp2();
```

Answer (score 3):

You get a compilation error because this line `(emp11).displayEmp2();` is an invalid Java statement. You have to give a Type (class name) inside the csating parenthesis

in addition, the downcasting has to be made in the same statement that is doing the method call. `emp11` is defined of type `Emp1`. it has to be explicitly casted everytime you wish to call a method from the subclass

```
Emp1 emp11 =  new Emp2(); 
emp11 = (Emp2) emp11;
emp11.displayEmp2();  // emp11 returned to type Emp1
((Emp2)emp11).displayEmp2();  // every call to emp2 method has to be explicitly cast
```

Comment: but it is instantiated using subclass only then in next step with explicit casting i can do this right ?